# How to create column-based DBs given data row by row efficiently

Tags: database, algorithm, data-analysis

I assume in column-based database, each column is stored as an individual file, or stored contiguously in a file. If the input data is still a row of data like the traditional row-based database, how can we create column-based database efficiently?

Storing each column in a file could 'simply' the problem...
If there are N columns, then there are N files. When a new row of data arrives, the database needs to append new data into each file. But will writing data into different files have overhead because of switching among different files? Maybe the blocks near the last write are still in cache. But if there are many columns (>1M), I am not sure the cache can hold all of them. Also I guess the disk head also needs to seek among different files...

If we save multiple columns in the same file, we can reduce the number of file handles, but inserting a new column data in the file is expensive. Maybe a reserved space could be reserved for each column in the file. But eventually the space is all used. At that time, do we want to create a new file with larger reserved space, copy data to it, ...?

Are there any papers or projects that explain how a column-based database is created from rows of data efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

That's the situation that is everybody faced with.

You dig some deeper in some area and understand some issues you want to solve. And even you have intuitive solutions for each issue, you could not resolve all of them. There is no silver bullet and as always, you win in some area and lose in other.

You've mentioned database creation aspect. But that's worth nothing without data extraction. For instance, you can create highly effective and fast way of creation the database, but that doesn't matter if data selection is very slow. Or...not, if your most common scenario is writing data.

And there are much more caveats as transactions, querying, etc. All of them need to be considered at the database architecture stage.

To conclude, there is always some trade-off and you as architect should define the goal and metrics of desired features to choose the implementation.

Similar tricks you can find in the area of distributed systems. For instance, [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) states that you cannot have system with all of three guarantees (Consistency, Availability, Partition tolerance). So some guys say: "We want C and A, and don't care about P". Other state: "oh, we definitely need C and P, and don't mind too much A". So there are [database systems meeting different kinds of wants](http://maxivak.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/media_httpfarm5static_mevIk.png).

You can find some papers regarding column-oriented databases to start with like [this one](http://db.csail.mit.edu/pubs/abadi-column-stores.pdf), [this](http://paperhub.s3.amazonaws.com/14d147739ca381a610b8eea771ab0c84.pdf) and [this presentation](http://nms.csail.mit.edu/~stavros/pubs/tutorial2009-column_stores.pdf).